# How do I check if a specific table exists in a database or not using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm asking because I want to include the code in an if statement to check if the selected table exists in the database or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following PHP code to check that table exist or not.

```
<?php
    $servername = "server_name";
    $username = "db_user_name";
    $password = "db_password";
    $dbname = "db_name";
    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $tableName = "table_name";
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$tableName'";
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Table exists";
    } else {
        echo "Table does not exist";
    }
    
    $conn->close();
?>
```